# What is the best practice to set parameter as dictionary type as default value in python

Tags: python-3.x, mutable

I tried to write a class with mutable object as default value. I know for a single function we should set parameter as None and check the parameter in case the side effect for the function like following code. But I was wondering how about when I tried to initialize a class?
side effect by using mutable object as a default value for a variable

```py
def func(k, v, para = {}):
    para[k] = v
    return para
print(func('a', 1)) #expect {'a': 1}, actually return {'a': 1}
print(func('b', 2)) #expect {'a': 1}, actually return {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(func('c', 3)) #expect {'a': 1}, actually return {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
#how about class?
class T
    def __init__(self, para = {})
    #or
    #def __init__(self, para = None)
        #para = para or dict()
        self.para = para
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know about that

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is the following.

Source: [Why is the empty dictionary a dangerous default value in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320899/why-is-the-empty-dictionary-a-dangerous-default-value-in-python)

```py
def func(k, v, para=None):
    if para is None:
        para = dict()
    para[k] = v
    return para
print(func('a', 1)) #returns {'a': 1}
print(func('b', 2)) #returns {'b': 2}
print(func('c', 3)) #returns {'c': 3}
```

And yes, I'm pretty sure the same applies to classes.

```py
class T:
    def __init__(self, para=None):
        if para is None:
            para = dict()
        self.para = para
```

---

Let's just test what happens with classes:

```py
class T:
    def __init__(self, k, v, para={}):
        self.para = para
        self.para[k] = v

print(T('a',1).para) #returns {'a': 1}
print(T('b',2).para) #returns {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(T('c',3).para) #returns {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

So yes, the same applies to class constructors.

Comment: I would suggest to explicitly test for `if para is None`. Because your test will create a new dict even if an empty one is passed, which might be surprising as the caller won't get the passed dict updated.

Comment: Agree. Good catch.