# Python memoization: necessity of passing back memo in recursive calls

Tags: python, recursion, memo

I just learned about memoization for optimizing recursive functions.  The solution for memoizing a Fibonacci function was provided as:

```
def fib_memo(n, memo={}):
    if n in memo : return memo[n]  
    if n in [1,2]: return 1
    memo[n] = fib_memo(n-1, memo) + fib_memo(n-2, memo)
    return memo[n]

print(fib_memo(50))

>>> 12586269025
```

However, I have found that the following variation (which **does not pass** `memo` in the recursive calls) also works as expected, but I am unable to explain how/why:

```
def alt_memo(n, memo={}):
    if n in memo : return memo[n]  
    if n in [1,2]: return 1
    memo[n] = alt_memo(n-1) + alt_memo(n-2)
    return memo[n]

print(alt_memo(50))

>>> 12586269025
```

When I run `alt_memo(n)`, is my compiler optimizing the code behind the scenes and adding `memo` in the recursive calls, or is it in fact not necessary to include `memo` in the recursive calls?

If not necessary, how is it that the recursive calls are receiving/passing-along the `memo` object (being as that the function initially sets the `memo` parameter to an empty dictionary, when otherwise unspecified)?

Comment: It works because you're modifying the dictionary in place, and all the calls share that same default value.

Comment: Thanks @match -- but if the function definition specifies that `memo={}` when undeclared, why does a recursive call that fails to pass memo not cause memo to become an empty dictionary during the subsequent execution of the call?

Comment: Sorry I misread the code. It's actually a different issue - see this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320899/why-is-the-empty-dictionary-a-dangerous-default-value-in-python

Comment: @ZwiTrader The default value is only evaluated once, when the function is defined, not every time the function is called.

Comment: @Barmar -- thanks this is very helpful to know (and completely clarifies the issue).