# mypy gives "Incompatible default for argument" when Dict param defaults None

Tags: python, mypy, pylint

I understand that a Dict parameter in a Python function is best set to a default of None. However, mypy seems to disagree:

```
    def example(self, mydict: Dict[int, str] = None):
        return mydict.get(1)
```

This results in the mypy error:

```
error: Incompatible default for argument "synonyms" (default has type "None", argument has type "Dict[Any, Any]")  [assignment]
```

mypy on the other hand is fine with this:

```
   def example(self, myDict: Dict[int, str] = {}):
```

But pylint complains:

```
W0102: Dangerous default value {} as argument (dangerous-default-value)
```

According to this SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26320917), the default should be None but that will not work with mypy. What is the option that will satisfy both pylint and mypy? Thanks.

**SOLUTION (based on comments):**

```
class Example:
"""Example"""
def __init__(self):
    self.d: Optional[Dict[int, str]] = None

def example(self, mydict: Optional[Dict[int, str]] = None):
    """example"""
    self.d = mydict
```

Part of the issue (not mentioned originally) I had was assigning back to a previously inited variable, this works.

Comment: Side note, if `mydict`  is `None`, then `mydict.get(1)` will result in an type error. Maybe you want something like `return mydict.get(1) if mydict is not None else None`. Or given your read-only usage of `mydict`, you could tell pylint to ignore this warning in this function.

Comment: btw solutions go in the answer boxes, not as an addendum to the question - that way people can upvote/downvote it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the type should be "`dict` or `None`", so a `Union` of the two:

```
def example(self, mydict: Union[Dict[int, str], None] = None):
        return mydict.get(1)
```

Comment: Or the shorthand `Optional[Dict[int, str]]`

Comment: Thank you, these work for me. This is closer to my actual code but these suggestions worked, see updated post.

Comment: @Dunes or even shorter `dict[int, str] | None` (assuming versions)