# Method not picking up default argument values and the local argument values persist between separate calls to the method

Tags: python, python-3.x

What should the following code print?

```
class C:
    def b(self,d = {'k':0}):
        print(d)
        d['k'] += 1
    def a(self):
        self.b()
c1 = C()
for i in range(3):
    c1.a()
```

I could have sworn it should be

```
{'k': 0}
{'k': 0}
{'k': 0}
```

since I am calling b `self.b()` without any parameters so it should pick the default value of `d` each time which is `{'k':0}`. I just don't know what I am overlooking here but it prints

```
{'k': 0}
{'k': 1}
{'k': 2}
```

What is wrong with the following two statements?

1. It should pick the default value of `d` when `b` is called without arguments
2. `d` should be local to the method `b` and should not persist between different calls to the method `b`

Comment: default values are evaluated *once* at function defintion time. It re-uses the *same object*, however, your method *mutates* that object, so of course, on another invocation, that change will be visible (because it is the same object)

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320899/why-is-the-empty-dictionary-a-dangerous-default-value-in-python and its duplicate target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument.

Comment: I've been on Python for about a couple of years now. I wonder how I survived without knowing something so basic. Thank you for the help guys. Keep rocking!!