# Redirect unknown attributes

Tags: python, selenium, oop, attributes

I'm building a custom class to add feautures to **selenium.webdriver.Chrome** on Python 3.6.2.

```
from selenium import webdriver

class MyChrome:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mydriver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

So far, beside some custom methods I made myself, I used to overridden some `selenium.webdriver.Chrome` very standard methods like this:

```
    def get(self, url):
        self.mydriver.get(url)
```

Since I don't want to waste time rewriting like that methods like `get`, `find_element_by_xpath`, etc... that already works fine for me I tried the following, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6321940/9364494) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075190/9364494)

```
def __getattr__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self.mydriver, name)(*args, **kwargs)
```

But when I run the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver

class MyChrome:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mydriver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def __getattr__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self.mydriver, name)(*args, **kwargs)

chrome = MyChrome()
chrome.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

I encounter the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyChrome.py", line 11, in <module>
    chrome.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
  File "MyChrome.py", line 8, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.mydriver, name)(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

**How do I redirect calls to unknown methods called on my object `chrome` to it's instance variable `self.driver`?**

Comment: `return getattr(self.mydriver, name)(self, *args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom Webdriver once to add features to selenium Chrome Webdriver and I did that by subclassing selenium Chrome Webdriver. This way you inherit all the webdriver methods without a getattr

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

class MyChrome(Chrome):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

 # add all your custom features
```

It doesn't provide answer to your question but something you can leverage

Comment: This is definitely the best approach. I should have extended `Chrome` class from the beginning. Anyway I was looking for another solution because at the moment I'm quite deep in this project and I'd prefer to avoid massively change the code.